# Given $f(x) = \frac{x^3}{3} - \sqrt{x^2+1}$, proof that $f(\alpha) = \frac{\alpha^4 - 3}{3\alpha}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I evaluated the function on $\alpha$ and removed the radical by multiplying by $\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}$ as follows:

$$ \frac{\alpha}{3} - \frac{\alpha^2 + 1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}} $$

After some algebraic manipulations, I got to this step:

$$ \frac{\alpha^4 \sqrt{1 + 1/\alpha^2}}{3\alpha\sqrt{1 + 1/\alpha^2}} - \alpha(1 + 1/\alpha^2)^{-1/2} $$

Does anyone knows if I am on the good track? or is there any hints that could help me? Thanks

Comment: What do you have to proof ? That there exists such an $\alpha$ ?

Comment: Does your alpha satisfy $ \alpha^3\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}=3$ ?

Comment: Consider $f(0)$, the first formula gives $f(0) = -1$ and by the second formula $f(0)$ is undefined.

Comment: @Falcon yes, $\alpha$ is a real number.

Comment: Do you have to prove "For all $\alpha\in\mathbb R$, $f(\alpha)=\cdots$", or instead "There exists $\alpha\in\mathbb R$ such that $f(\alpha)=\cdots$"?

Comment: Separate the fraction: $$\frac{\alpha^4-3}{3\alpha}=\frac{\alpha^4}{3\alpha}-\frac{3}{3\alpha}=\frac{\alpha^3}{3}-\frac{1}{\alpha}.$$ Then you just need to solve the equation $$\frac1\alpha=\sqrt{\alpha^2+1}.$$

Comment: Who's $\alpha$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{x^3}{3}-\sqrt{x^2+1}=\frac{x^4-3}{3 x}$$
$$\frac{x^3}{3}-\frac{x^4-3}{3 x}=\sqrt{x^2+1}$$
$$\frac{1}{x^2}=x^2+1$$
Substitute $x^2=w$
$$\frac{1}{w}=w+1\to w^2+w-1=0\to w=\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)$$
the root $w_2=\frac{1}{2}\left(-\sqrt{5}-1\right)$ is discarded because is negative. The solution is:

$$x=\sqrt{\frac{1}{2}\left(\sqrt{5}-1\right)}$$

Comment: There is only one solution because $$\frac1x={+\sqrt{x^2+1}}.$$

Comment: @mr_e_man Thank you!